# Modx Revolution can't find its CSS files?

Tags: zip, installation, modx, modx-resources

Here's an odd one: I just installed ModX Revolution 2.2.4 and all went well, but in the back end its like the css file is missing - it either loads just some of the page, or the whole page with no CSS.

In my browser console it says it cannot find the css file at all. I checked the files and directories - all are intact and all permissions are correct.

I've tried reinstalling and on two different servers both with the same occurrence.

The only thing that came up is that during the installation it couldnt unzip the file core.transport.zip, so I unzipped it on my PC and re-uploaded it.

Would anyone know whats going on at all?

Thanks

Comment: normally you wouldn't need to unpack the transport packages yourself. Did you install into a subdirectory?

Comment: Actually yoshi, yes I did install it into a sub directory

Comment: I have often had the same problem after moving modx to a subdirectory, though never after a fresh install. You might want to try again without unpacking the transport packages. Also have a look here: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Troubleshooting+Installation

Comment: Yeah I have. I get the same error both times...I've also gone back to 2.2.2 with the same results. Very frustrating!

Comment: also check this: http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/MODX+and+Suhosin

Comment: What are the permissions on the css file and the directory containing it?

Comment: @okyanet all permissions are fine -  all 7s

Comment: Try uploading the `setup` folder again and rerun the install. Does that fix it?

Comment: Copy and paste the full css path out of your html source (from the rendered page) and into a new tab. Does it load? Is the path correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the zipped files within ModX were not unzipping when I did the install. Either unzip them on your PC, fix or update the PHP on the server, or install an older version (2.1.7 works ok)